# Function to find number of words in a file using C++?

Tags: c++, loops, count, while-loop, cpu-word

`while (ch != '\0') {
    if (isWhiteSpace(contents[i-1]) == 1)
      countWords++;
    i++; 
    }`

I'm trying to print the word count in a text file. I've already defined a function isWhiteSpace, which return 1 if the char is white space, otherwise it returns 0. I've tested the isWhiteSpace function and it works properly. I added this code to my word count function and I'm getting a segmentation fault error. I've tried multiple methods within the while loop of getting the word count and they've compiled, they just didn't return the correct number, so it's not a problem outside the while loop. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Since `ch` never changes, the loop doesn't end until `contents[i-1]` is something you shouldn't be accessing, hence the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

A google search for "word count C++" yields [this answer on another stackexchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49038/count-number-of-words-in-a-text-file):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: count_words <infile>\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);

    std::istream_iterator<std::string> in{ infile }, end;

    std::cout << "Word count: " << std::distance(in, end);
}
```

This solution is so nice that I think it deserves a bit of explanation. `istream_iterator` will do whitespace tokenization for free. Thus you could manually count the words by iterating over the range `in` to `end`. However, the standard algorithm `distance` does exactly that for you by counting the number of elements in a range.

Comment: @FabioA.Correa: You should probably look up how `istream_iterator` works. This is correct. The `end` iterator is not uninitialized, it has a default constructor that initializes it.

Comment: Absolutely right; deleted comment. Sorry for the inconvenience.